# WP_Query for showing specific post by id

Tags: wp-query

but it just shows the first post, I need to show three posts, please help me

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(

 'p' => '272 282 292',)); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>

  // Do Stuff
endwhile;
endif;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 11):

For multiple post IDs, in `WP_Query` arguments, we can use:

```
'post__in' => [ 272, 282, 292 ],
```

but for a single post ID it's:

```
'p' => 123,
```

Note that the default post type is `post`.

### Checking out the SQL query

It's informative to checkout the generated SQL query of `WP_Query`.

Try e.g. in the [wp-cli](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/shell/) shell:

```
wp> $q = new WP_Query( [ 'post__in' => [ 272, 282, 292 ] ] );
wp> echo $q->request;
```

That way you can make sure it's generating what you need.

Compare e.g. the `post__in` and the `p` case.

### Helpful docs

It's also helpful to look at the Developer's Handbook:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

and in some cases the old Codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: nice answer , I dont know why its not been marked as an answer , can you please tell what if i want all post with id starting from 145 , similar to Like 145%. Is it possible with wp_query ?

Comment: Glad to hear helped. This will need a custom solution eg with a custom filter. Recently posted similar but for wp-cli and user: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/329515/wp-cli-show-users-whose-id-is-larger-than-given-id/329559#329559. Dont know if its helpful here though.

Comment: yes I think I have to do custom sql query because I checked in Users section in wp-admin and there too wordpress does not allow to search the way I said before. Thanks